# .net and jsReport templates

Tags: asp.net-core, jsreport

I am trying to use jsReport with templates. But can't figure out where does jsReport searches for template names.
What is a typical folder structure for jsReport?

I am using jsreport.Local for .net core.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand the structure of stored templates is to run the jsreport studio right from your project, create some templates and see how the files looks like.

You should take a look to the section `Locally stored templates` in the [jsreport.Local documentation](https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local#locally-stored-templates) describing how to run the studio from your project. The same example can be seen also in the [introduction video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqTGQgkEHow).

Comment: I haven't installed the whole package. I want just to generate the report and get the byte[]. Doesn't jsreport provide an API documentation?